# Select multiple element not empty validation engine without required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I need to do validation that at least one element is selected. This element was filled dynamically and I need to validate if that I have at least one option element selected, using validation Engine.

Here fill the select option item

```
jQuery("#bt_add").click(function(){
    storeUsedGroups[attr_group.val()] = true;

    jQuery("#atributo_id").append('<option value='+attr_name.val() + 
        ' groupid='+attr_group.val()+'>' + attr_group.text() + 
        ' : ' + attr_name.text()+'</option>'
    );
});
```

and validate with required, but for submit form need select the options inserted.

```
<select name="atributo_id[]" id="atributo_id" multiple="multiple" class="validate[required]">
    <option value="5" groupid="1">Color : Azul</option>
</select>
```

I just need to validate non-empty the element.

Comment: Do you mean one option selected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Why don't you show us what you have so far?  You'll find the community is far more helpful when we can see the effort you've put in to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If I understand you correctly you want to apply required rule only if select element was populated with options.

You can do that with custom function call. Change your select's class to

```
<select name="atributo_id[]" 
        id="atributo_id" 
        multiple="multiple" 
        class="validate[funcCall[ifSelectNotEmpty]]">
```

Now the function

```
function ifSelectNotEmpty(field, rules, i, options){
  if ($(field).find("option").length > 0 && 
      $(field).find("option:selected").length == 0) {
     // this allows the use of i18 for the error msgs
     return "* This field is required";
  }
}
```

It supposed to be working, but it won't because `jquery.validationEngine.js` crashes on line 707 (IMHO it's a bug). So you need to change line 707 from

```
if(!required && && !(field.val()) && field.val().length < 1) options.isError = false;
```

to

```
if(!required && !field && !(field.val()) && field.val().length < 1) options.isError = false;
                ^^^^^^
```

**Original answer**
If you want to check if any of options has been selected you can do it like this

```
if (!$("#atributo_id option:selected").val()) {
    alert("Nothing has been selected");
}
```

or

```
if (!$("#atributo_id option:selected").length) {
    alert("Nothing has been selected");
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/KSe7L/)**

Comment: Initially the select element is empty without options items, and I need that validation when I do submit the form. Using validationEngine, probably I need to use a custom regex, And if use required class forces me to select it.

Comment: Yes, at least one option. Using validationEngine.

Comment: @Angel Do you need more help with the question?